# Phantomjs and delayed javascript

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I have an analytics script on my website that fires events after 1 second, 5 seconds and 1 minute. I want to test this with Phantomjs, but I cant get them to execute. The initial javascript loads, but the subsequent timed events do not fire.
The analytics script is hosted on the analytics provider domain, and I only reference it on my page to collect analytics data.
It doesn't work with a  wait or a `window.setTimeout()`

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

edit: This is my phantomjs code

```
var page = require('webpage').create();


var myArray = ['Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1464.0 Safari/537.36', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.12) Gecko/20080219 Firefox/2.0.0.12 Navigator/9.0.0.6','Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)','Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; MS-RTC LM 8; Zune 4.7)','Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; Zune 4.0; Tablet PC 2.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)'];
page.settings.userAgent = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length)];

page.viewportSize = { width: 1920, height: 1080 };

var url = 'myurl.com/mypage.html'; 

page.open(url, function () {

    window.setTimeout(function(){
    page.render('');
    phantom.exit();
    },5000);

 });
```

Comment: Timeouts work fine in phantom - are you sure it's not some support issue with your analytics script?

Comment: @jraede when I open the same page in a broser such as firefox or chrome it works fine!

Comment: "are you sure it's not some support issue with your analytics script?" meaning, maybe it doesn't support Phantom for whatever reason

Comment: @jraede I am sure it works fine for phantom. What I know about the analytics code is this: It loads a javascript after a particular ad has loaded and then that javascript has a timer built in which makes updated requests to the analytics server about the time passed and other details etc., now I know this because it is a simple GET request, which I can see from my sniffing tool (Charles)

Comment: Maybe I'm not following - how do you see the GET request for time passed if the `setTimeout` isnt running?

Comment: @jraede I see the GET request on my firefox/chrome using a network sniffer, that is how I know how the code works. But in phantom, even on waiting for 60000 millisec, there is no GET request after the analytic js has been initially executed

Comment: RIGHT, so maybe your analytics code doesn't support phantom, which is why you aren't seeing the GET request. That's what I've been saying from the beginning.

Comment: I have been in touch with the analytics provider and they say that it should work with any browsers and even with headless ones for testing purposes. So I know for a fact that it does work on any browser. Even headless ones. @jraede

Comment: IMO "it should work with any browsers and even with headless ones" does not lead to "know for a fact that it does work on any browser".

Comment: @jraede lets just assume it works. What could be wrong with Phantom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it seemed that the analytics code only fired if the browser had
`document.hasFocus()` return `true`